# I have a array of objects to check from that primary is true is only one time on the checkbox otherwise show alert

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-material, ionic4, angular8

I have a array of objects to check from that primary is true is only one time on the checkbox otherwise show alert see image below :-

[image: Primary no check on 2nd time check]

```
 <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="primary" formControlName="primary"> Make this primary </mat-checkbox>
```

In this array of object there are 2 primary = true in that

Comment: Very vague question. Please tell us what exactly you want?

Comment: Please clarify what you expect and create a Stackblitz example, if possible

Comment: I want to make only one primary no .. show how to check on second time to show alert that you have already primary other no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your array is `data`.

```
let primaryGuys = data.filter(person => person.primary === true);
if(primaryGuys >1) {
   alert('HEY!')
}
```

Comment: Here we filter out all items with `primary: true` and see if there exists more that 1 such cases. Please accept answer if worked!